# How to use rich:dataTable with row selection without binding

Tags: jsf, binding, scope, richfaces, javabeans

I'm currently migrating a legacy project from JSF 1 (with RichFaces 3) to JSF 2 (with RichFaces 4). The project has several rich:dataTables with checkboxes next to the items. At the bottom of the page, there are a few action buttons to so something with all selected items (add to favorites, export as PDF, ...).

The checkboxes are the reason why the rich:dataTables have a binding to the corresponding UI beans. But most of the UI beans are session-scoped. In between, I've learned that binding in combination with session-scope is not a good idea. And indeed, I'm having lots of "duplicate ID" errors that go away if I change the scope to "request". But it's not that easy. These beens have some state that needs to be preserved between requests and an elaborated state initialization and cleanup logic.

I think I have two options:

1. change the beans to request-scope, do some massive refactoring by extracting the state into some new "stateObjects" to be saved in a new "sessionBean", and completely rewrite the state logic
2. remove the bindings, but how can I determine which entries of the rich:dataTable have their checkboxes selected?

Curiosly, the session-scope and bindings worked together very well with JSF 1. And  the decision for making the beans session-scoped was made a long time before I took over the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove binding and change actions (bean scope changing not needed).

1) **Simple case**: data table with list of items and after row selection detail for selected item is displayed

Following example uses *Javascript* (storing item ID in bean and calling action for presenting data related to this ID):

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="selectRow" action="#{locationAction.showSelectedLocation}">
    <a4j:param name="locationId" assignTo="#{locationAction.selectedLocationId}" />
</a4j:jsFunction>

<rich:dataTable id="locationTable"
    value="#{locationAction.locationList}" var="location"
    rows="#{referenceData.recordsPerPage}"
    onrowclick="selectRow('#{location.locationId}')">
    ...
</rich:dataTable>
```

2) **Case with multiple check boxes** and action button:

```
<rich:dataTable id="productTable" var="res"
    value="#{productPicker.pickerList}">
    ...
    <rich:column>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectChck" value="#{res.selected}" />
    </rich:column>
    ...
</rich:dataTable>
<a4j:commandButton value="#{msg.detachSelected}"
    action="#{productPicker.deleteSelectedFromPickerList}"
    render="picker" />
```

where item list is `private List<PickerItem> pickerList;` and item is from

```
public class PickerItem {
    private Long id; // with getter and setter
    // private Record item; // with getter and setter
    private boolean selected; // with getter and setter
}
```

In my code there are `equals` and `hashCode` methods as pat of PickerItem class, but it should works without it too.